# ListView repeated items when scrolling and DB

Tags: android, listview

I've this code, the problem is that I got repeated elements when I scroll. I solved this getting out part of the code from the if(item==null) but then i'll do a lot of DB calls instead of the 6 that i need (for six elements)

Leaving the code as you see, i got only 6 DB calls, but also repeated items... I read a lot of about this here and there, but I don't understand how this works...

I read also somethig about clear elements in the layout, but didn't understand at all...
Could you help me, please?

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView totales;
    TextView falladas;
    TextView nota;
    CheckedTextView checkList;
}

public class AdaptadorTemas extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Activity context;

    public AdaptadorTemas(Activity context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.elementos_lista_url, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) { // es llamado cada vez que se muetras un elemento de la lista


        if(item == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);

            //here I do some sql querys to fill the holder variables
            //...


            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.totales = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblPreguntas);
            holder.falladas = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblFalladas);
            holder.nota = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblNota);
            holder.checkList = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.checkList);

            item.setTag(holder);

            //then I fill the variables
            holder.falladas.setText(strFalladas);
            holder.nota.setText(nota);
            holder.totales.setText(totalRespondidas + "/" + totales + " - " + porcentaje + "%");
            holder.checkList.setText(values.get(position));

        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
        }

        return item;


    } // getView


} // class
```

Thank you guys for your answers, but in the end I stored each element in a ArrayList (with the data) and asked in every getView for that element in the ArrayList, a little bit hard to understand how a listView with a holder works for me...
Here the code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) { // es llamado cada vez que se muetras un elemento de la lista

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        final String elemento = values.get(position);
        int totalRespondidas = 0;
        int falladas = 0;
        int totales = 0;
        int porcentaje = 0;
        String nota = "-";
        String strFalladas = "";

        if(item == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.totales = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblPreguntas);
            holder.falladas = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblFalladas);
            holder.nota = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblNota);
            holder.checkList = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.checkList);

            item.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
        }

        boolean loTenemos = false;
        int i = 0;

        for(i=0; i<elementos.size(); i++){
            String[] dividido = elementos.get(i).split("#");

            if(dividido[0].equals(elemento)){
                //System.out.println(elementos.get(i) + " coincide con " + elemento);
                loTenemos = true;
                //System.out.println("encontrado en " + i + " de " + elementos.size());
                break;
            }

        }

        if(loTenemos){
            //here i get the data from the vector

            vCounter ++ ;
            System.out.println("vector " + vCounter);

            String[] datos = elementos.get(i).split("#");
            falladas = Integer.valueOf(datos[1]);
            nota = datos[2];
            totalRespondidas = Integer.valueOf(datos[3]);
            totales = Integer.valueOf(datos[4]);

            holder.falladas.setText(strFalladas);
            holder.nota.setText(nota);
            holder.totales.setText(totalRespondidas + "/" + totales + " - " + porcentaje + "%");
            holder.checkList.setText(values.get(position));

        }
        else{

            //here I get the data from the DB
            //and stored it in the Vector
            elementos.add(elemento + "#" + falladas + "#" + nota + "#" + totalRespondidas + "#" + totales);

        }
```

Comment: i think it you adpter problem just try to add this code with adpter::


CustomAdapter adpter=new CustomAdapterthis);
adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adpter);
listView.invalidate();

Comment: didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

Make your `ViewHolder` and inner class of your class `AdaptadorTemas`.

```
static class ViewHolder {
TextView totales;
TextView falladas;
TextView nota;
CheckedTextView checkList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder holder; 
    if(item == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.totales = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblPreguntas);
        holder.falladas = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblFalladas);
        holder.nota = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblNota);
        holder.checkList = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.checkList);

        item.setTag(holder);
         }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
    }
        holder.falladas.setText(strFalladas);
        holder.nota.setText(nota);
        holder.totales.setText(totalRespondidas + "/" + totales + " - " + porcentaje + "%");
        holder.checkList.setText(values.get(position));

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should  fill the variables    value out side of condition ...

```
if(item == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);

        //here I do some sql querys to fill the holder variables
        //...


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.totales = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblPreguntas);
        holder.falladas = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblFalladas);
        holder.nota = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblNota);
        holder.checkList = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.checkList);

        item.setTag(holder);

        //then I fill the variables

    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
    }
        holder.falladas.setText(strFalladas);
        holder.nota.setText(nota);
        holder.totales.setText(totalRespondidas + "/" + totales + " - " + porcentaje + "%");
        holder.checkList.setText(values.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your getView method because it sometimes clears the view and then only creates the view again not their values, therefore, you need to fill the data again. Or you can save the data of sql queries in some way like in memory or in sqlite etc, and you can read there afterwards if its already there.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) { 

        if (item == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);
        }

        //check data if its in sqlite if not query your database and then save it in sqlite or static list etc whatever you choose
        strFalladas = getDataFromSomewhere();
        ...
        ...

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.totales = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblPreguntas);
        holder.falladas = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblFalladas);
        holder.nota = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.lblNota);
        holder.checkList = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.checkList);

        item.setTag(holder);

        //then I fill the variables
        holder.falladas.setText(strFalladas);
        holder.nota.setText(nota);
        holder.totales.setText(totalRespondidas + "/" + totales + " - " + porcentaje + "%");
        holder.checkList.setText(values.get(position));

    return item;


} // getView
```

Comment: then, for what .setTag()??